# Is this a new RPi 3B revision?

Tags: pi-3b+

I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 3B board, but comparing it to other units I have seems somewhat different. It has the processor of the 3B+ model, the BCM2837B0, instead of the BCM2837 of 3B model. Also USB ports seem to be the same as the 3B+ instead of the 3B.
PCB layout is the same as 3B, as well as its Wifi chip, and when trying to get the internal identifiers, it shows the same info as 3B;

Hardware : BCM2835
Revision :    a22082

cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/model
Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2

[image: pi3b comparison]

1. Pi 3B
2. Pi 3B (new)
3. Pi 3B+

3B and 3B+ shown in the image are manufactured in the UK instead of China, as on the 3B not so plus model.

Is this a known new revision of the 3B model? I haven't found any information about it.

Greetings.

Comment: What does the following command report? `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Revision`

Comment: Could you identify the boards in your picture? Write a sentence above or below stating which one is which.

Comment: Below picture you can now find a list with model numbers. Upper one is 1, lower one is 3.

Comment: The middle one is from China, not UK.

Comment: @joan Ack! Useless use of `cat`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The revision code is in the format `uuuuuuuuFMMMCCCCPPPPTTTTTTTTRRRR`.

```
a22082 == 1 010 0010 0010 00001000 0010

F = 1 (new format revision code)
MMM = 010 (2) (1GB) 
CCCC = 0010 (2) (Embest)
PPPP = 0010 (2) (BCM2837)
TTTTTTTT = 00001000 (08) (3B)
RRRR = 0010 (2) (rev2)
```

So it's just one that's been made by Embest rather than Sony.

Nothing new to see here.

Comment: As I said, trying to get internal identifiers results in getting the same numbers as in "normal" 3B, but as you can see in the picture, processor is different from "normal" 3B, being the "normal" the upper one in the photo and the "new" the second one. The third one is a 3B+ only for reference.

Comment: It's made in a different factory. They're allowed to change components where needed to fit their local supply chain. If it waddles like a Raspberry and quacks like a Raspberry what's the problem?

Comment: No problem at all. BCM2837B0 is a better/newer version of the processor. Until now, it was only used in 3B+, and I was trying to know if this was a new version of the 3B model, cause it has not been announced but it's an improvement over the normal specs.