# Are there different versions of raspberry pi 3B+?

Tags: pi-3b+

I have one 3B+ card that was bought some time ago (maybe ~1year).
I have been using this as a testing PC.
Yesturday I recived two new 3B+ cards (rough visual inspection they look the same as older).
As I'm doing some testing I need to install a stretch image to one of these and downloaded the latest stretch image (http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/raspbian-2019-04-09/)
I flashed this to a memory card but the new 3B+ is refusing to boot. (Green led blinks 4 time)
If I put the same card in my 1year old 3B+ it boots without problems.
Both the new 3B+ cards behave exactly the same
(If I install latest Raspberry PI OS to the card then both new cards boot as intended. So they do not seam to be broken)

Are there different versions of the 3B+ card and how do I detect this?
Any ideas to how I can get the two new 3B+ to boot with stretch?

Small update:
There are some component difference between the cards. The one to the left is the older that boots fine. The one to the right is the one that is not complying with my testing.
[image]

Edit: I'm new here but there have apparently been linked an answer to my question. Its stated that if I do not feel it answer my question I'm requested to edit my question explaining why.
So the link to the supposed answer to my question is this post: [Is this a new RPi 3B revision?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105757/is-this-a-new-rpi-3b-revision)
In my opinion that does not answer my question as the 3B+ that is shown in that picture is same as the one that is booting for me. But the one to right side in my picture have small difference in component setup compared to answer.

Comment: As far as I know, there are no "different" Raspberry Pi versions of a model. It is possible that you simply got unlucky and received a faulty RPI. They should both have the same specs.

Comment: Why do you need to use Stretch?

Comment: In the end it comes down to me not knowing enough about Linux and what all makes it tick. Some years back I bought some software that was made for raspberry pi (Stretch). This software is not updated anymore and there is no replacement option (within my budget). So to be able to continue use this(that is a absolute must) I need to stick to stretch

Comment: Apparently there are different as yo use from my picture. There are some component differences above the power connector(yellow marking in picture).

Comment: @Friendlygabe777 There are possible cosmetic differences (eg., color of the PBC), partially because some models have been made in several different places.  Also, they do in fact have revisions, which imply there is some real difference (even if this is just different manufacturers, see duplicate Q). @Confused You can check those w/ `grep Revision /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: Sorry took some time as I did not have a memory card that it could boot from ready :) Anyway I get Revision : a020d4 as cpuinfo

Comment: cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/model gives Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Blus Rev 1.4

Comment: What is the software you bought?

Comment: It was mySCADA for raspberryPi. (From www.smarthouse.cloud not available anymore). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BSnSRw5OrY